# Eclipse: Is there a clean way to remove a field from a structure in a large project?

Tags: eclipse, ide, eclipse-cdt

I want to modify the definition of struct foo and remove (not rename) a field "x". This is a large codebase and foo.x is used in a large number of places.

Can I automate the process of searching for usages of foo.x and be prompted to modify each such instance, preferably in eclipse-cdt? #askingforafriend

Comment: Comment out foo x, and save foo.  Remove all the lines of code mentioning foo x.  Remove foo x.

Comment: Let me clarify my question. The solution you mentioned involves manually searching for each instance. What I am looking for is a way to automate the task of searching each instance and modifying it. An example is the refactoring window which provides a preview of the files and code affected and the user can choose what to keep.